# How do i change font color in the sample pages of asp.net-core mvc

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-core-mvc

Learning some asp and bootstrap here. I'm playing with the default sample pages of asp.net-core 2. Changing stuff. The font color is some kind of gray everywhere. I've changed de background color to black, so i would like to make font color brigther. I guess its in bootstrap.css or bootstrap.theme.css, but those are preaty big files, maybe someone could give me some shortcuts. Thanks!

For example this h2 text and the text in the li elements

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h2>Application uses</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Sample pages using ASP.NET Core MVC</li>
        <li>Theming using <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398939">Bootstrap</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to use css for this? You can also use bootstrap 4 classes but that is not working in this code. I already tried it. @niutudis

Comment: I was thinking about changing the default values of it. But i dont know wich is the best way. You mean using css to override them? @MeghnaBhuptani.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess its in bootstrap.css or bootstrap.theme.css, but those are preaty big files

You don't have to change the compiled bootstrap css file. And you'd better not. In that case, it'll be difficult to maintain  your code.

One way is to create a `css` file to override the styles defined in bootstrap.css. But I would suggest you should custom the `Bootstrap` directly as [the official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults) describe.

1. run `npm init -y` in your project directory.
2. run `npm i bootstrap --save-dev` to install the `bootstrap`
3. install `node-sass` by `npm install node-sass -g` if you don't have one.
4. create a `custom.scss` in your project directory, and override the variables as you like. As a demo, I change the background color to `#212529` and the font color to `#fff`:

   ```
   // the default color variables, you might want to custom it
   $white:    #fff !default;
   $gray-900: #212529 !default;

   // override the default variables
   $body-bg: $gray-900 !default; 
   $body-color: $white !default;
   // ... you might want to override other default colors for modal/carousel/card/...
   //     feel free to override these variables if you need

   // import the whole bootstrap
   @import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
   ```
5. Run cmd `node-sass .\scss\custom.scss wwwroot/css/bootstrap.custom.css`.

(This approach works fine for Bootstrap v4 (The ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC template uses Bootstrap V4 by default). If you're using V3, please download the [Bootstrap ported from Less to Sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) (install by `npm install bootstrap-sass`) and make it in a similar way)

---

Now you get a custom bootstrap css file, change your `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` to reference this custom style file:

```html
    <environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.custom.css" />
```

Finally, because the default template uses a light theme in the `navbar`(**hard-code**), you need to change your nav bar to use `navbar-dark`/`bg-dark`/`text-light`:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">App</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: That look like an awsome response to me. I haven't tried it yet, but looking forward to do so. Thanks! @itminus